# Calcular pi com o sequencia em python

Tags: python

Um programa que calcule `X` pela série: `4-4/3+4/5-4/7+4/9-4/11...` com precisão de `10^-4`

tenho feito assim, mas ele lista os termo e não soma. O que q está errado?

```
n = 1  
while True:  
    n = n + 1  
    termo = (-1) ** (n + 1)  
    resultado = (termo * (4 / (2 * n - 1)))  
    if n == 10:  
        break  
    print(f'{resultado}')
```

Comment: Você tem que **acumular** em resultado e não apenas atribuir. Lembre-se de inicializar com 0. Para calcular de acordo com a precisão pedida calcule a diferença entre o resultado atual e o resultado anterior, se for menor que 10^-4 encerre o loop.

Comment: Seu cálculo do sinal está com problemas. Você parte de `n = 1`, faz `n = n + 1`, isto é 2 e aí faz `(-1) ** (n + 1)` ou seja o primeiro termo terá sinal negativo quando deveria ser positivo. Além de não considerar o denominador `1` para o primeiro termo.

Comment: acho q entendi, para falar a verdade eu não sou nenhum programador aprendo por hobbie então eu sou mt leigo kkkkk

Comment: A = 4  
resultado = 0  
n = 1  
divisor = 1  
termo = A  
while abs(termo) > 0.0001:  
    resultado = resultado + termo  
    n = n + 1  
    divisor = divisor * n * (2 * n - 1)  
    termo = (-1)**(n + 1) * A / (2 * n - 1)  
print(resultado)  

fiz assim no final das contas e tem dado certo

Answer (score -1):

Uma possível solução é:

```
n = 1
resultado = 0
sinal = 1
while True:
    termo = sinal * (4.0 / n)
    if termo < 0.00001:
        break
    resultado += termo
    n += 2
    sinal = -sinal
print(f'{resultado}')
```